# tcl regex inside string map

Tags: regex, dictionary, tcl

I got a template which I want to transform into a tex file. For example each chapter and section which contains a dot and a letter I want to replace it with a backslash and the letter. I know I can try using regsub, but I really want to try it with string map, here is the code which is not working:

```
set main \
{
.chapter{Assignment 1}
.section{1a}
}
set main [string map {.({^[A-Za-z]+$})\1 \\\1} $main]
```

It will be easier to do just:

```
set main [string map {.c \\c} $main]
set main [string map {.s \\s} $main]
```

But I just want to try using the {any letter thingy} and to know if is possible using the `string map` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [string map manual entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) this command does not take a regular expression. String map takes a simple list of strings to match with values to substitute in place. It has a -nocase option to enable case independent matches but that is all. However, you can have multiple pairs eg:

```
string map {.c \\c .s \\s} $value
```

You can also use normal Tcl scripting to build up a more complex list of pairs if you want as that mapping is just a list. If you want or need to use regular expressions, then you must use regsub.